# Is it necessarily true that there exists an element of G of order d?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group, and let d be a proper divisor of $|G|$. Is it necessarily true that there exists an element of G of order d? Give a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: What are your ideas? Have you looked at $S_3$? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest counterexample for this claim can be found by looking at an elementary abelian group of order $8$, i.e. $G \cong C_2^3$.

Then $4 \mid 8$ (as a proper divisor) but every non-identity element in $G$ has order $2$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not true.  In $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ for example, there are no elements of order $9$ even though the order of the group is $27$.

However, this statement is *always* true if $G$ is cyclic.   (Why?).